(Firebase Dynamic Links) Deeplink URL not opened in browser on iOS devices
In firebase console, I create a new dynamic link that set "Open the deeplink URL in a browser" for Apple.

When I test pressed the link on the my iOS devices, it successfully open the app but it does not open the URL in a browser.
I already setup the necessary Associated Domains in the project Signing & Capabilities section. Here is my repo as reference to replicate the issue, https://github.com/Blurzschyter/firebaby-alpha
Appreciate if anyone can assist me to solve the issue.
Tested on iPhone 14 Pro (iOS 16.5) & iPad Air(5th-Gen) (iOS 18.0.1).
I know Firebase Dynamic Links will be deprecated on Aug 2025, but I want to explore if there is any solution that can solve my issue.
Here is my Podfile setup,

Here is my AppDelegate setup,


Have you checked the app site associated domains file in your URL ?
"http://website.com/apple-app-site-association" you can check the path for deeplink here, must return JSON

@GoksuBayy yes...already checked, it return JSON as per this {"applinks":{"apps":[],"details":[{"appID":"my-App-ID","paths":["NOT /_/","/"]}]}}

The "paths" seems correct. Sometimes need to remove then install the app to change behavior. Have you tried that ?

@GoksuBayy yes...I have tried remove then install the app again, but the issue still persist.
